# using java's executor service with a non-static method

Tags: java, methods, lambda, executorservice, non-static

I've been writing a programm, which opens a window and if you close it,it will open two new ones. It's working fine, but I tried to change the color of all windows by using the executor service, which is calling my function ColorChanger.

**The Problem is**: If I want to use the executor service, I need a static method, but if I want to use the `this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);` command, I have to use a non-static function.

If you need further information, please have look at my code, everything should by self-explaining:

```
public class SplittingWindow extends JFrame implements WindowListener,KeyListener {

    int width = (int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
    int height = (int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight ();
    Random rand = new Random();
    String Input = new String();
    static ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> ColorChanger(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        new SplittingWindow();
    }  

    SplittingWindow(){
        addWindowListener(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(100,100);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocation(rand.nextInt(width-150),rand.nextInt(height-200)+50);
    }

    public void ColorChanger(){
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {  
        System.out.println("closing");
        new SplittingWindow();
        new SplittingWindow();
        dispose(); 
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        Input = Input + e.getKeyChar();
        if(Input.contains("JayJay")==true){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }


    // Removed various interface methods  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe fqct is you need to instanciate the object if you want to use a method of hs class without making it static :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SplittingWindow sp = new SplittingWindow();
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> sp.ColorChanger(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

try this and it should work

Comment: Why are you creating two instances of `SplittingWindow`?

Comment: @korolar because it's a fun program which creates two windows every time you close one